# Keras - Fusion of a Dense Layer with a Convolution2D Layer

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras, keras-layer

I want to make a custom layer which is supposed to fuse the output of a Dense Layer with a Convolution2D Layer.

The Idea came from [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2925974) and here's the network:

[image: The Network]

the fusion layer tries to fuse the Convolution2D tensor (`256x28x28`) with the Dense tensor (`256`). here's the equation for it:

[image: The Fusion Formula]

`y_global => Dense layer output with shape 256`
`y_mid => Convolution2D layer output with shape 256x28x28`

Here's the description of the paper about the Fusion process:

[image: capture3]

I ended up making a new custom layer like below:

```
class FusionLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(FusionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = input_shape[1][1]
        initial_weight_value = np.random.random((input_dim, self.output_dim))
        self.W = K.variable(initial_weight_value)
        self.b = K.zeros((input_dim,))
        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b]

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        y_global = inputs[0]
        y_mid = inputs[1]
        # the code below should be modified
        output = K.dot(K.concatenate([y_global, y_mid]), self.W)
        output += self.b
        return self.activation(output)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

I think I got the `__init__` and `build` methods right but I don't know how to concatenate `y_global` (256 dimesnions) with `y-mid` (256x28x28 dimensions) in the `call` layer so that the output would be the same as the equation mentioned above.

How can I implement this equation in the `call` method?

Thanks so much...

UPDATE: any other way to successfully integrate the data of these 2 layers is also acceptable for me... it doesn't exactly have to be the way mentioned in the paper but it needs to at least return an acceptable output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to ask this question on the Keras Github page and someone helped me on how to implement it properly... here's the [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4505) on github...

Answer (score 5):

I was working on a project of Image Colorization and ended up facing a fusion layer problem then I found a model containing fusion Layer.
Here it is Hope that solves your questions to some extent.

```
    embed_input = Input(shape=(1000,))
    encoder_input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1,))

    #Encoder
    encoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_input)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2,
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)
    encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(encoder_output)

    #Fusion
    fusion_output = RepeatVector(32 * 32)(embed_input)
    fusion_output = Reshape(([32, 32, 1000]))(fusion_output)
    fusion_output = concatenate([encoder_output, fusion_output], axis=3)
    fusion_output = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(fusion_output)

    #Decoder
    decoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(fusion_output)
    decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same',
                            bias_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))(decoder_output)
    decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)

    model = Model(inputs=[encoder_input, embed_input], outputs=decoder_output)
```

**here is the source link:** https://github.com/hvvashistha/Auto-Colorize

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion implementing a new kind of layer is a way to complicated for this task. I strongly advise you to use the following layers:

- [Flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten),
- [Merge](https://keras.io/layers/core/#merge),
- [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense),

in order to obtain the expected behaviour.