# Keras fusion a fixed size Dense Layer with a dynamic Conv2D Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a network architecture proposed by [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2925974).**And I have seen the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810619/keras-fusion-of-a-dense-layer-with-a-convolution2d-layer).**

[image: architecture]
[image: formula]

And there is a Fusion Layer whicn I have some trouble to implement.

Because the **mid_level_network output's shape is not fixed** `(None, H/8, W/8, 256)`, and **the global_network output's shape is fixed** `(None, 256)`.

I have used the following code to implement.

```py
def fusion_layer(mid_level_output, global_output):
    repeat_time = mid_level_output.shape[1] * mid_level_output.shape[2]
    global_output = RepeatVector(repeat_time)(global_output)
    target_shape = (mid_level_output.shape[1], mid_level_output.shape[2], global_output.shape[2])
    global_output = Reshape(target_shape)(global_output)
    fusion_output = Concatenate()([mid_level_output, global_output])

    return fusion_output
```

But When I call this function, it raise a error.
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

```py
def low_level_feature_network(low_level_input):
    X = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(low_level_input)
    X = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)

    return X

def mid_level_feature_network(mid_level_input):
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(mid_level_input)
    X = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)

    return X

def global_feature_network(global_input):
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(global_input)
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(X)
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(X)
    X = Dense(512, activation='relu')(X)
    X = Dense(256, activation='relu')(X)

    return X

# dynamic output shape : mid_level_output
low_level_no_scaling_input = Input((None, None, 1))
low_level_no_scaling_output = low_level_feature_network(low_level_no_scaling_input)
mid_level_output = mid_level_feature_network(low_level_no_scaling_output)

# fixed output shape: global_output
low_level_scaling_input = Input((224, 224, 1))
low_level_scaling_output = low_level_feature_network(low_level_scaling_input)
global_output = global_feature_network(low_level_scaling_output)

# fusion two layers however the errors raised
fusion_output = fusion_layer(mid_level_output, global_output)
```

How can I fusion these two different type shape layers together.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic shapes it's better to use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/shape?version=stable

So mid_level_output.shape[1] should be K.shape(mid_level_output)[1], where K is keras.backend.

Also a Keras layer is more than just a function, for your implementation of fusion_layer, either use a Lambda layer, or subclass tf.keras.Layer. Finally it looks like you might be forgetting about your batch size (dimension 0).